# Haskell type resolution in Type Classes

Tags: haskell, type-inference

Haskell seems to be having trouble resolving 'g == [a]' when performing type inference. Any ideas how to make this work?

Thx

```
module X where

import Control.Monad.State.Lazy

class Generator g where
  next :: State g a

instance Generator ([] a) where
  next = nextL

nextL :: State [a] a
nextL = state $ split

split :: [a] -> (a, [a])
split l = (head l, tail l)
```

Comment: The `a` in your class has no relation to the `a` in your instance, so you need to give `next` a value of the type `State [a] b`, or more likely fix your class declaration somehow.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to recreate [`MonadSupply` and `Supply`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-supply/docs/Control-Monad-Supply.html)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Reid's right in his comment. When you write

```
class Generator g where
  next :: State g a
```

you're really saying

```
class Generator g where
  next :: forall a. State g a
```

so that from a given state in `g`, your clients can generate an element of whatever type `a` they wish for, rather than whatever type is being supplied by the state in `g`.

There are three sensible ways to fix this problem. I'll sketch them in the order I'd prefer them.

Plan A is to recognize that any generator of things is in some sense a container of them, so presentable as a type constructor rather than a type. It should certainly be a `Functor` and with high probability a `Comonad`. So

```
class Comonad f => Generator f where
  move :: forall x. f x -> f x
  next :: forall x. State (f x) x
  next = state $ \ g -> (extract g, move g)
  -- laws
  -- move . duplicate = duplicate . move

instance Generator [] where
  move = tail
```

If that's all Greek to you, maybe now is your opportunity to learn some new structure on a need-to-know basis!

Plan B is to ignore the comonadic structure and add an *associated type*.

```
class Generator g where
  type From g
  next :: State g (From g)

instance Generator [a] where
  type From [a] = a
  next = state $ \ (a : as) -> (a, as)
```

Plan C is the "functional dependencies" version, which is rather like MonadSupply, as suggested by Cirdec.

```
class Generator g a | g -> a where
  next :: State g a

instance Generator [a] a where
  next = state $ \ (a : as) -> (a, as)
```

What all of these plans have in common is that the functional relationship between `g` and `a` is somehow acknowledged. Without that, there's nothing doing.

Comment: Should that perhaps be `Generator NonEmpty`?